# How can I deploy/resolve Maven artifacts to/from a private github repo using m2eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, github, m2eclipse

I have built an internal library for my team and would like them to be able to include it in their projects using Maven.  Is it possible to publish it to my private Github repository so they can access it?  Ideally I would like to do this using m2eclipse without needing the Maven command line interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best suggestions i can make is to use a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) which will make it simple to offer others the artifacts which they can use in the usual maven way via a dependency.
*Update*
In the nexus book it's described how to setup nexus, secure it and make restriction by user etc. to restrict access to the nexus.

http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/

Comment: My main reason for wanting a private Github repo was the ease of keeping it private and secure.  Would you be able to point me towards a resource on how to restrict access to a running instance of Nexus?  I think that this could solve my problems.